# Pandas conditional ffill

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to achieve the following: Start should be zero until R column is below 20, then positive until R column is above 80 and the cycle should repeat (reset). Up to row 19, the behavior is as expected, yet on row 20 Start is inexplicably set to 1 despite not matching criteria. Adding extra columns is fine.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=100), columns=['R'])
df['Start'] = np.where((df.R < 20), 1, 0)
df['End'] = np.where((df.R > 80), 1, 0)
df.loc[df['End'].shift().eq(0), 'Start'] = df['Start'].replace(0, np.nan).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
```

```
     R  Start  End
11  82      0    1
12  63      0    0
13  37      0    0
14  21      0    0
15  88      0    1
16   9      1    0
17  13      1    0
18  83      1    1
19  47      0    0
20  68      1    0
21  42      1    0
22  67      1    0
23  26      1    0
24  79      1    0
25  87      1    1
26  96      0    1
27  39      0    0
28  50      1    0
29  94      1    1
30  95      0    1
```

**Solution** as per Quang Hoang's answer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=100), columns=['R'])
df['Start'] = np.select([df['R'] < 20, df['R'] > 80], (1,0), np.nan)
df['Start'] = df['Start'].ffill()
df['Start'] = df.Start.combine(pd.Series(np.insert(abs(np.diff(df.Start)), 0, 0)), max, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: So you only care about the `start` column?

Comment: Start is the signal to activate and I'm trying to slice until the End condition is met. Then watch for another start condition and repeat. Effectively I'm trying to avoid looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `np.select`:

```
df['Start'] = np.select([df['R']>80, df['R']<20], (1,0), np.nan)
df['Start'] = df['Start'].ffill()
```

Output:

```
     R  Start  End
11  82    1.0    1
12  63    1.0    0
13  37    1.0    0
14  21    1.0    0
15  88    1.0    1
16   9    0.0    0
17  13    0.0    0
18  83    1.0    1
19  47    1.0    0
20  68    1.0    0
21  42    1.0    0
22  67    1.0    0
23  26    1.0    0
24  79    1.0    0
25  87    1.0    1
26  96    1.0    1
27  39    1.0    0
28  50    1.0    0
29  94    1.0    1
30  95    1.0    1
```

Comment: np.select([df['R'] < 20, df['R'] > 80], (1,0), np.nan) is very close to what I was going for, I'd only like the last Start value (when R > 80) to also be a positive match.

Comment: if it's the last one, you can find and mask it before `ffill()`.

Comment: Was not able to use mask successfully, but a slightly more cumbersome addition works df['Start'] = df.Start.combine(pd.Series(np.insert(abs(np.diff(df.Start)), 0, 0)), max, fill_value=0). I will assume however that this has serious performance drawbacks.

Comment: `df.iloc[::-1]['R'].gt(80).idxmax()` would give you the lass occurrence of `R > 80`.

Comment: Should've been clearer. I meant the last of every occurrence. So when `R > 80`, start column still has 1. The solution in the question posted has the expected result. Thanks so much.